# R: How to pick rows of a data frame that match a criteria but not filter out others

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume a data frame that look something like this:

```
set.seed(42)
seqs <- sapply(1:20, FUN = function(x) { paste(sample(letters, size = 11, replace = T), collapse = "") })
annot1 <- sapply(1:1000, FUN = function(x) { sample(c("A", "B","C"), size = 1, replace = T)})
annot2 <- sapply(1:1000, FUN = function(x) { sample(c("X", "Y","Z"), size = 1, replace = T)})
values <- rnorm(n = length(annot1), mean = 1, sd = 1)
df <- data.frame(id=sample(seqs, size = length(annot1), replace = T), annot1, annot2, values)
```

I would like to get the rows that have a value above a given threshold, e.g. `value > 1.5` in either 1 or all 3 conditions (but not 2), denoted by variables `annot1` or `annot2`. For the ids that match this criteria, I want all values (not only the ones above the threshold).

My usual approach which consists of chaining `filter()` and `n_distinct()` doesn't work in this case since it will filter out observations where the value isn't above the threshold, which creates issue when I go to wide format later on to do clustering on these variables.

I have thought about creating intermediate variables and use them to pick up ids but it feels like there must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Please add the desired result to your question.

Comment: If your conditions are a combination of `annot1` and `annot2`, wouldn't you have 9 possible conditions, not just 3?